# my server does not pass Server Certificate Revocation check

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

When this Internet explorer setting is enabled ::: Internet Options -> Avanced -> Security -> Check for server certificate revocation.

My website fails the check. Also, on google chrome 6+, the address bar displays a broken security lock.

My website is https://www.centredegenetique.ca

I need advice on how to determine what is causing these errors and how to fix it.

My certificates are valid from Starfield technologies. However, it looks like something is missing.

Also: I am using ubuntu 10.04 and apache2.2

Comment: Strange, I just checked here with chrome and everything is ok. Are you sure the dates on your computer are correct?

Comment: Did you install any intermediate certs provided by Starfield on your web server?

Comment: Hello, yes I have the intermediate certs installed. The internet explorer settings is changing a value in the registry which instructs windows to check for more security. When it is checked, all browser fail the check when using https. The way I understand it, the browser look for server certification revocation check but fails it.

Comment: No idea if it's related but I've had some issues with those intermediate certs, they need to be installed quite specifically and their old friends need to be properly removed from the web server first - at least on IIS and Windows... Starfield had a 5 page walk-through to get that right or some specific devices would fail the check.

Comment: I have an opera v11.50 and I see the same problem both with my own site (also starfield SSL) and yours. But in IE 8.0 everything is just fine. So at least you are not alone. I have not been able to find a solution yet :( and I see you have not either :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL Shopper's SSL Checker seems to think [everything's fine](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://www.centredegenetique.ca/) with your SSL setup.

It sounds like you've got a local problem with OCSP - perhaps you've got your machine configured to validate all certificates through a single OCSP provider, and that provider doesn't exist, can't be reached (routing/DNS problem?) or isn't configured to answer OCSP queries for sites where it didn't issue the cert.